# Adding next.line() style argument within iterator loop

Tags: python, iterator

I'm trying to loop through two columns in specific rows from a genome file (first 50 lines are in `bam.txt` below) and output the values between these columns (i.e. if row 1 is 5000-7000 and row 2 is 9000-10000, i want 7001-8999 in a new dict). I set this up by computing the distance between columns, adding this to the first value, and then subtracting one from the value on the next line. I've read the documentation and similar questions, but the variants of file.next() are still pulling the value from the same line.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4gjbgrjtdafngev/bam.txt

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict
infile=open('bam.txt', 'r')
intronic={}
exonic={}
intron=0
for line in infile:
    if (line[0] != '#') and re.search("exon", line):
        eee = re.split('\t', line)
        exonF = eee[3]
        exonR = eee[4]
        exonic=OrderedDict()
        exonic[exonF]=exonR
        for value,key in exonic.iteritems():
            intronsize=int(key)-int(value)
            intronF=int(value) + intronsize + 1
            ##line=line.next()##  <-------- jump to next line here
            intronR=int(value)-1
            intronic=OrderedDict()
            intronic[intronF]=intronR
            print intronic
```

Comment: `line = infile.next()`

Comment: Your code inside for loop isn't indented.

Comment: fixed (copy+paste error).

Comment: I don't follow what you want to achieve by 'the ranges between these columns', can you be more clear?

Comment: `line` is just a string. It has no `next` method. It doesn't even know it came from a file.

Comment: Don't jump to regexes for everything. Instead of `re.search("exon", line)`, you could just write `'exon' in line`. Similarly, instead of `re.split('\t', line)`, you could just write `line.split('\t')`.

Answer (score 0):

`next()` is a method of `file`: http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects

You call `infile.next()` to read the next line of the file. As pointed out by Bakuriu, compatibility with python3 suggests the use of `next(infile)` instead (which has the same effect in python2, though).

As the doc says,

> A file object is its own iterator

In your case, the `for` loop on the file object iterates on the lines, calling `next()` implicitly at each loop.

Comment: Thank you for responding. When I replace my commented line with this one, the output has not changed. I've nested it within another for loop as well. Maybe it's the way I'm storing the values in dicts?

Comment: you are not really using `line` in your second loop, that could be why. you possibly want to split it again, although I have not analyzed what you are doing in details.

Comment: I'd suggest to use `next(the_file)` instead of `the_file.next()` because it works also in python3, where `next` was renamed `__next__`. The `next()` function allow also the use of a default value in case of termination which comes in handy some times.

Comment: I'm still very new to python (it took me 2 hours to write the above code) so I am still unsure how to actually place the next function into the loop.

Comment: here is what I don't understand : why do you loop on the content of `exonic` when there is only 1 item in it?

Comment: @vieuphoria you can't really place the next function in the loop, you normally use the `continue` keyword to go to the next line, but you need to have the code able to handle 'being on the next line' in some way.

Comment: @njzk2 by that point in the loop, exonic is filled with columns 3 and 4 from all lines containing the search string "exon"

Comment: @vieuphoria : no because `exonic=OrderedDict()` makes `exonic` a new empty dict.

Comment: @vieuphoria no it isn't, at that point it's got one thing in it. You start the loop, put one thing in it, take it out, then next time through the loop you create a new empty OrderedDict for exon and do the same again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you want to achieve, but ...

Every time through the loop, `exonic` is being recreated as a new empty dictionary, so is `intronic` in the next loop.

`iteritems()` returns `key, value` instead of `value, key` that you're writing.

I supsect you could use lists instead of OrderedDicts.

You don't need regular expressions here.

This is approximately what I'd be doing, one run through the file to get the lines and then another run through the lines *keeping track of the previous line* to calculate the differences between lines:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

infile = open('bam.txt', 'r')
intron=0

line_results = []

for line in infile:
    if not line.startswith('#') and 'exon' not in line:
        eee = line.split('\t')
        exonF = int(eee[3])
        exonR = int(eee[4])

        line_results.append(exonF, exonR))

prev_line = (0,0)
for line in line_results:
    exonF, exonR = line
    prev_exonF, prev_exonR = prev_line

    intron_size = exonR - exonF

    intronF = prev_intronR + 1
    intronR = exonF + intronsize + 1    #I don't know if this is what you want

    print intronF, intronR, intron_size
    prev_line = line
```